# Nativescript Angular iOS - "registerElement" leads to "Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

for the last 2 months I've been working on a Nativescript app for Android, now I want to bring it to iOS as well so I bought a MacBook and set everything up (which already took days). Now I am at a point where I can build the app for iOS without an error but it does not run on the emulator. The error it throws is quite unspecific:

```
(UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.BeYou[0x3de3][1786][11743]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
```

I found the reason to be "registerElement". I use it for two plugins:

```
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry"; 
registerElement("StatusBar", () => require("nativescript-statusbar").StatusBar);
registerElement("CardView", () => require("nativescript-cardview").CardView);
```

When I comment out line 2 and 3, the app starts as intendet. As soon as I uncoment one of them, the app crashed after start (without actually showing the home page).

Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you already for your help!

/e: Building and running Android works without a problem with the same code on the same machine, tns doctor doesn't show any problems.

Comment: why not just add them to node modules?

Comment: Well, both plugins are in the node_modules folder if you mean that. Using "registerElement" is the way to go for these plugins according to their docs - but if you know how to add them a different way I would be very happy

Comment: The only time i registered an element was when i couldnt add it to the node modules, so im not sure

Comment: it seems that the nativescript-statusbar plugin is causing the segmentation error in Angular app.

Comment: Not exclusively, only disabling nativescript-status bar also yields the segmentation error (in my case)